# How to move a tank in top-down perspective?

Tags: box2d

I am trying to build a box2d game in top-down-view with a tank (could also be a car).
The tank can be rotated with dpad left/right:

```
direction = inputSource.getDirection();
if (direction != 0) {
    body.applyAngularImpulse(direction * 0.5f, true);
    if (body.getAngularVelocity() > 1f) body.setAngularVelocity(1f);
    else if (body.getAngularVelocity() < -1f) body.setAngularVelocity(-1f);
}
else body.setAngularVelocity(0f);
```

The tank can be accelerated with dpad up and decelerated with dpad down.
The tank should always move with the actual velocity in the direction it is heading (angle)
The tank has to change the movement direction immediately after changing the angle.

And that is the problem with box2d in top-down-perspective because the linear velocity doesn't care about the angle of the body.

How can I solve this?

I already tried calculating and setting new velocities after the angle has changed.
that works but I had some strange effects (i guess due to interpolation)

What the state-of-the-art approach would be to solve the problem?

Comment: How about modeling it the way it is in the real world, with a force pushing on each side of the tank. You could use ApplyForce to push it at two separate points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current velocities magnitude. Then you create a direction vector in the direction of the bodies angle. Multiply the direction vector by the previous velocities magnitude and you've got your new velocity.

You mentioned interpolation. You could make the object have an angle and a targetAngle and interpolate between those each frame, this would smooth the motion out. [Libgdx Box2D smooth angular rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039186/libgdx-box2d-smooth-angular-rotation/25049015#25049015)

This isn't really using the physics engine, it's overriding it to get the behavior you want.

If you do want to do this using the physics engine for everything then you'd have to use torques to rotate in the direction you want. Use linear drag to slow down your body a bit each frame, and accelerate in the direction of the bodies angle.